# GLSL Variables Not Getting VBO Data

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013, glsl

There must be something wrong with how I'm implementing my VAOs and VBOs because my shader isn't getting any of the buffer data I'm allocating to it. It could be something to do with the location of the variables. I tried printing out the location value from glGetUniformLocation (my loc variable), and it printed out 4294967295 for every location value. I would think there's a different location for each of them. I also tried using the location (location = ...) values from the vertex shader and that didn't work either. Any extra insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my rendering code:

```
// load shaders and textures to the current context
glUseProgram(cloudShader);
glActiveTexture(cloudTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cloudTexture);
glEnable(GL_POINTS);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glPointSize(10.0f);

// initial velocity and start time buffer
GLuint vbo[3];
// texture position buffer
GLuint textPosBuf;

glGenBuffers(3, vbo);
//glGenBuffers(1, &textPosBuf);

// gen vao object
GLuint vao[3];
glGenVertexArrays(3, vao);

// define uniforms
glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(cloudShader, "color1"), color1.r, color1.g, color1.b, color1.a);
glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(cloudShader, "color2"), color2.r, color2.g, color2.b, color2.a);
glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(cloudShader, "Accel"), accel.x, accel.y, accel.z);
glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(cloudShader, "color1Wght"), color1Wght);
glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(cloudShader, "Time"), time);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(cloudShader, "MVP"), 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(mat4(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX) * mat4(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)));
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(cloudShader, "ParticleTex"), cloudTexture);

GLfloat *data = new GLfloat[nParticles * 3];
// I then set data ...

// bind vertex buffer data

// initial velocity data
glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nParticles * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), reinterpret_cast<void*>(data), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

// VertexInitVel attrib array pointer setup
GLuint loc = glGetUniformLocation(cloudShader, "VertexInitVel");
glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, NULL, NULL);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc);

// start time data
data = new GLfloat[nParticles];
// I then set the data...

// load start time buffer data
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nParticles * sizeof(GLfloat),
    reinterpret_cast<void*>(data), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

// InitStartTime attrib array pointer setup 
loc = glGetUniformLocation(cloudShader, "StartTime");
glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, NULL, NULL);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc);

// buffer texture position data
data = new GLfloat[nParticles * 2];
// I then set the data...

glBindVertexArray(vao[1]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nParticles * sizeof(GLfloat), 
    nParticles * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), reinterpret_cast<void*>(data));
loc = glGetUniformLocation(cloudShader, "texCoordIn");
cout << loc << endl;
glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, NULL, 
    reinterpret_cast<void*>(nParticles * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc);

// buffer particle position data
data = new GLfloat[nParticles * 3];
// data gets set...

glBindVertexArray(vao[2]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[2]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nParticles * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat),    reinterpret_cast<void*>(data), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
loc = glGetUniformLocation(cloudShader, "VertexStartPos");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc);
glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, NULL, NULL);

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, nParticles);

// cleanup 
....
```

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 450

// information to pass to the fragment shader
out vec2 texCoord; // texture coordinate to pass to fragment shader
out vec4 color1Pass;
out vec4 color2Pass;
out float color1WghtPass;

// Initial velocity and start time
layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexInitVel; 
layout (location = 1) in float StartTime;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 VertexStartPos;  // where particle "respawns"
layout (location = 3) in vec2 texCoordIn;

//  various values
uniform vec4 color1;
uniform vec4 color2;
uniform float color1Wght; // how strongly color1 is weighted
uniform float Time;  // Animation time
uniform mat4 MVP; 
uniform vec3 Accel;  // Particle acceleration

out float Transp;  // Transparency of the particle
const float ParticleLifetime = 10.0f;  // Max particle lifetime


void main()
{
    // Assume the initial position is as defined by Vertex Start Pos.
    // vec3 pos = VertexStartPos;
    vec3 pos = vec3(0.0);
    Transp = 0.0;
    // Particle doesn't exist until the start time
    if( Time > StartTime ) {
      float t = Time - StartTime;
      // particle is born
      if( t < ParticleLifetime ) {
        pos = VertexInitVel * t + Accel * t * t;
        Transp = 1.0 - t / ParticleLifetime;
      }
    }
    color1Pass = color1;
    color2Pass = color2;
    color1WghtPass = color1Wght;
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(pos, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: You're using `glGetUniformLocation()` instead of `glGetAttribLocation()` to get attribute locations.

Comment: That was likely part of the problem, but even after changing that, the shader is still not getting the attribute data properly.

Comment: You might get better response if you simplify the code to something smaller that still reproduces your problem. There could be a whole number of issues here. For example, it looks like you never call `glBufferData()` for `vbo[1]`. You have a `glBufferSubData()` call, but that will only work if there was an earlier `glBufferData()` call.

Comment: I apologize for not trimming down the code as much as I could have for the post, but that thing you pointed out my ordering of calls for the bufferdata being out of whack was spot on. I needed to move the glBindVertexArray(vao[1]); call to be above the previous glBufferData() call. That combined with switching in the glGetAttribLocation() calls and combining everything into one vao seemed to fix the problem. Thanks again, you're a life saver. I'll try to be better about trimming up my code in future posts to make it easier to look at.

Comment: I meant to say the glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]); call; I ended up getting rid of the second vao object.